# Security of PHP exec() with pdftk utility

Tags: php, security, pdftk

I'm interested to use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (the pdft toolkit) by calling it from a PHP script. I intend to use the [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function for this. The command would follow this format:

`pdftk [form_file] fill_form [data_file] output [output_file] flatten`

This command takes a form PDF file (`form_file`) and inserts the FDF data from `data_file` and flattens the form and saves it as `output_file`.

Here is what I'm thinking to secure the execution of this command via a function like `exec()`

- Directory and file names are not user-defined. Directory and file names are generated based on sanitized identifier strings and will only contain alphanumeric characters, dashes, underscores, and periods. The identifier strings will have a limited, practical length.
- Arguments (filenames) are passed through [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) before being concatenated into the command (though this is probably unnecessary if the proceeding step is free of vulnerabilities).
- The entire command is passed through [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

Am I overlooking any security vulnerabilities when it comes to executing this command? (The only one I can think of now is if there is a vulnerability with pdftk itself and how it processes the files.) Any suggestions to improve this process? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `escapeshellcmd` on the whole thing if you've already used `escapeshellarg` on individual arguments or you'll end up escaping twice.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Hmm, would it? The documentation for `escapeshellcmd` states "Following characters are preceded by a backslash: #&;\`|*?~<>^()[]{}$\, \x0A and \xFF. ' and " are escaped only if they are not paired." I believe since it states that it only escapes them _if they are not paired_ that it is okay, since `escapeshellarg` would add paired quotes.